# Cant find and enable FrontPage Server Extension on IIS or Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Here is an screen shot of what I have:
[image]

My book is saying right click and Select "All Tasks"  but I can't find such a thing. What is the troubleshooting I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPSE has been obsolete by Microsoft, and handed over to Ready-to-Run as a commercial product,

http://www.rtr.com/fpse/Win2008R2/index.htm

You either buy it from Ready-to-Run, or switch to WebDAV,

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-webdav/how-to-migrate-fpse-sites-to-webdav

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot, hope it helps.
http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2011/07/frontpage-2002-server-extensions-for-iis-70-on-windows-server-2008-and-windows-vista